# Search form with PHP and PDO then display results on page

Tags: php, sql, search, pdo

I am trying to search my SQL database with a simple search form and then return the data to the screen.

For example, the user can select a year, then all the row results from the table display all of the information for that entry. Here is my form:

```
<form class="" method="POST" action="availability.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <select class="form-control mb-3"  name="year" id="year">
                      <option disabled selected>Year</option>
                      <option value="2019">2019</option>
                      <option value="2020">2020</option>
                      <option value="2021">2021</option>

                    </select>

                    <input class="btn btn-blue-grey" type="submit" value="submit">Search
                    <i class="fas fa-search ml-1"></i>
                    </input>

                    </form>
```

And here is my PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$year = $_POST['year'];

var_dump($year);
var_dump($_POST);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM availability WHERE year = :year";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':year',$year,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(); }
```

and my HTML

```
<ul>
                            <?php foreach($data as $stmt)  { ?>
                                <li><?php echo $stmt['cruise'];?></li>
                                <li><?php echo $stmt['year'];?></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
```

At the minute, the form submits, but I get nothing populating the list.. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I dont see where you set `$query` to any actual value?

Comment: Should that not be `$stmt->execute(array("%$year%"));`

Comment: And what does the column `year` contain, if it is just the value like `2019` the the query could be written as `SELECT * FROM availability WHERE year = :year` and would be much more efficient

Comment: I have changed that value.. but still getting nothing in return :(

Comment: Maybe you should show us the schema for the `availability` table and maybe some example rows from it as well

Comment: I'll edit my question to updated code

Comment: To be anymore help we will need to see the schema and some sample data. Remeber we are working blind here

Comment: Heres a php eport of the table..

Comment: @RiggsFolly im not sure he bound `$year` to `:year` in his query

Comment: Ahh Good point missed that @KebabProgrammer

Comment: @sayou has posted a correct answer

Comment: Hmmm I have updated code as suggested.. but still getting nothing displaying :/

Comment: have you set `$data` to the value of `$stmt->fetchAll()`? use some intuition

Comment: `return $stmt->fetchAll();` won't do anything for you, you need to set the value of `$data` to `$stmt->fetchAll()` and then loop through it with foreach and display the data.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to edit the loop here. I have already done that as edited code above

Comment: what problems are you having now?

Comment: After I submit the form I just get an empty <ul></ul>. Sorry for being a noob.. i'm just learning haha

Comment: I even changed the short tags for php and still getting nothing

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this query :

```
$year = $_POST['year'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM availability WHERE year = :year";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':year',$year,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I have updated the search query but still nothing wants to display in the html :(

Comment: @ChrisWare I edited the query, please on the end of it use `var_dump($data)` and share with us the result, if you can please share with us the structure of your `availability` table on database

Answer (score 0):

you must change a few thing,
first,  edit the select tag to:

```
<select class="form-control mb-3"  name="year" id="year">
                      <option disabled selected>Year</option>
                      <option value="2019">2019</option>
                      <option value="2020">2020</option>
                      <option value="2021">2021</option>

                    </select>
```

There is a condition that seems it is wrong.
so, change your html code to

```
if($_POST) {

$year = $_POST['year'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM availability WHERE year = :year");
$stmt->execute(array("%$year%"));
// fetching rows into array
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();}
```

Comment: You didnt answer the question m8

Answer (score 0):

$stmt->bindParam(':year',$year,PDO::PARAM_STR); <-- does this need to be PARAM_INT ?

also have you var_dump'ed $year = $_POST['year']; to make sure you are getting a value?

You could turn on error_reporting and see if you get any useful errors

Comment: also, and it might be a silly question but I have seen it happen - do you actually have any data in your database for the year you are selecting?

Comment: There is definitely entries in the table for that year. The database coloumn is an INT so I have changed the PARAM_STR to PARAM_INT with no luck. Excuse my ignorance.. ill have to look up how to var_dump haha

Comment: at the top of you php add error_reporting(E_ALL) and after $year = ... write (var_dump($year));  you might as well var_dump($_POST) while you're at it :)

Comment: I have added error_reporting(E_ALL); to the top of the page and added the var_dump in as shown above. Do i need to echo these anywhere to see results? Cause nothing is coming up..

Comment: Chris, is you php running on a different script to your html? i.e are you submitting the form, running the php and then redirecting back to the html page?

Comment: If i change the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) to if(isset($_POST['year'])) it seems to work... and automatically defaults to 2019...

Comment: Should I do it on different pages?

Comment: haha Chris, you've accidentally diagnosed the problem.  Isset($_POST['submit']) doesn't work because the submit input does not have a name.  if you add in name="submit" your form will work

Comment: also no, it shouldn't be different pages, I was wondering if that's what was going on

Comment: Haha thank goodness this is fixed! Cheers for the help everyone!!

Comment: a classic case of not seeing the wood for the trees.  Welcome to debugging(!)